# Duplicated code vs easy merging

Tags: iphone, git

I have working code in master. I need to create new app as a new branch, which has additional functionality, that is similar with what is already in master. I also need from time to time do merging changes from master to new branch.

I've tried following approaches:

> 1. Create new classes separately, despite of they have similar functionality  + there's no problems with git merge master
>
>    - There's duplicated code
> 2. Create abstract classes for common functionality, then inherit from it old master classes and new branch classes   + there's no duplicated
>      code
>
>    - There's permanent problems with git merge master
> 3. It's modification of #2 - move abstract classes to master branch - resolves two above mentioned problems but
>
>    - There's unnecessary (abstraction) code in master

So which way is preferred? Or is there correct (another) solution?

**Update:**
added #3.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal solution would be to isolate the abstract classes in a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)**, and make the parent repo (the one with master and your new application branch) use said submodule.
Ie look for the common class in a subdirectory in which the submodule (which is a separate git repo in itself) resides.

That way, you keep separate:

- the merges between master and app
- the evolutions of the common classes (done in their own git repo, imported as a submodule in your main repo)

Comment: What is the advantage of moving common (abstract) classes to submodule rather than keeping them in master branch (#3)?

Comment: @M.Y. the history associated with that stable set of API is isolated in its own repo, allowing you to reference a precise point in time (tag or SHA1) of that submodule, and allowing you to dissociate the tags (V1, V2, V3...) of your main application (or of your new application) from the tags you would set on that submodule: your app V4.3 can use V2.1 of the common API: two different development lifecycles.